# Stop windows from changing geometry directly after being opened in GNOME using fly-pie?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

I recently noticed that when I start an application using [fly-pie](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3433/fly-pie/) on Ubuntu, the window either opens in the top left corner or in the center (depending on the org.gnome.mutter center-new-windows setting), but then jumps to the cursor position. This would normally be fine, however, as I am using [BurnMyWindows](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4679/burn-my-windows/) to animate windows, it causes the animation to play in the original position, and then the window jumps somewhere else. Is there a way to stop this from happening?

After some digging in the source of fly-pie, I found that new windows get created like [this](https://github.com/Schneegans/Fly-Pie/blob/2d3a48ad973fdf7d52e3e5c20c191d60e5f4938c/src/common/menus/Favorites.js#L68), from gjs Shell.App open_new_window() (however, I still haven't found what puts the new window on to my cursor position...)

Comment: Try using Gnome Tweaks to set the window location. I used it to center windows and it seems to work reliably.   .....   https://itsfoss.com/make-applications-start-at-center-ubuntu/#:~:text=Method%201%3A%20Use%20GNOME%20Tweaks%20to%20center%20new%20application%20windows&text=Once%20installed%2C%20open%20the%20Tweaks,'Center%20New%20Windows'%20feature.&text=If%20you%20want%20to%20get,it%20in%20the%20same%20way.

Comment: I have already tried this. The problem is that, for some reason, applications opened specifically by fly-pie always jump to the cursor position after initially opening where you had set it in the gnome tweaks window location. This is not true for applications started from the task bar or keybinds, as these open and stay where gnome tweaks set them to

Comment: I am not sure what is wrong with your OS.  I have this working well here,  I will do some thinking.

Comment: It may be the app you are using. Try a general Linux cleanup.  .....   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove
   .....   Run sudo apt full-upgrade to renew packages and remove old ones